# How to View NodeJS SSL Negotiation Results

Tags: node.js, ssl

I'm creating a nodeJS server using HTTPS, similar to this:

```
var https = require('https');

function listener(req, res) {
    // for example, I wish this worked...
    console.log(req.chosen_cipher)
}

var httpsd = https.createServer(SslOptions, listener);
httpsd.listen(8081, opts.ip);
```

How can I find the SSL negotiation results (in particular the selected cipher), for example ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, etc.

I've serialized the req & res objects, but there doesn't seem to be any likely candidates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_class_tls_tlssocket) for current connection is `req.client`.

So, to get cipher and protocol call [`tlsSocket.getCipher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getcipher):

```
function listener(req, res) {
    console.log(req.client.getCipher());
    // Possible result: 
    // { name: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256', version: 'TLSv1/SSLv3' }
}
```